# Indirect modification of overloaded property - cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I experienced this error during my ajax form validation.

```
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property CommentsController::$data has no    effect [APP\Controller\CommentsController.php, line 78]
```

the specific line stated in the error is this:

```
$this->data['Comment'][$this->params['form']['field']] = $this->params['form']['value'];
```

my cakephp version is 2.1

they said that it is working in 1.3 but what specific code am i going to use as a replacement to make it compatible with 2.1??

Answer (score 11):

It is

```
$this->request->data
```

You should [read the Migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html).

---

Since Cake3.4 it is

```
$this->request->getData()
```

See [the related migration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-4-migration-guide.html) guide for 3.4 :)

Comment: it is still not working. the error disappeared but it didn't show any output